# Sublime Typescript

Tags: typescript, sublimetext3

If I have two typescript files, let's say a.ts and b.ts
a.ts content is:

```
export class A {
    greet():void{
        console.log("hi");
    }
}
```

b.ts content is:

```
export class B {
    constructor(){
        var a:A=new A();
        a.greet();
    }
}

new B();
```

I want to compile these files with https://github.com/Railk/T3S and/or https://github.com/lavrton/sublime-better-typescript

The problem is that if I compile the file b.ts, it cannot see the file a.ts whether I add a.ts to the project or not.
So, I wrote a compile.bat file (I use it as a build-system), which collects the files into a txt, and then I use the command like this:

```
dir DIRECTORY\*.ts /b /s > DIRECTORY\ts-files.txt
tsc @DIRECTORY\ts-files.txt --outDir OUTPUT_DIRECTORY
```

It works great (all the js files compile well) but when I see the source in the editor, it still doesn't recognize the references in other files.

So, I have a buld-system, it works great. If I use T3S, it works great, but only with one file, without any outer reference.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does using a reference comment help to solve your problem - it tells the compiler where to look for dependencies: `///<reference path="a.ts" />`

Comment: Yes It can solve this problem. The interesting thing is that when I use webstorm, it doesn't need reference comments.

Comment: WebStorm and Visual Studio both automatically scan the project for files - this is a bonus IDE feature rather than a direct TypeScript compiler feature :)

Comment: Ahh I see, I thought it's something magic by something unknown, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the project grows, you usually end up with circular dependencies/references: `A` references `B` which references `C` which references `A`...

The only way we found out of this is to write a single definition file, say `definitions.d.ts`, which references **all**  Typescript files

```
///<reference path="A.ts" />
///<reference path="B.ts" />
///<reference path="C.ts" />
```

Then, in each Typescript file, there is single reference to `definitions.d.ts`

```
///<reference path="definitions.d.ts" />
```

**EDIT**

As an alternative, move to `require`: for CommonJs "style", use the `tsc` flag

```
--module commonjs
```

and in the Typescript files, `import` the resources

```
import A = require('./A')  //no .ts in the name
```

Comment: Thank you, I think that's the way I'd like to try!

Answer (score 0):

Not all integrated development environments auto-scan for TypeScript files.

Visual Studio and WebStorm will treat all files in the project as implicit references (this in itself can cause problems sometimes if you *don't* want to reference a file - but most of the time it is a useful feature).

Outside of these IDEs, you need to supply reference comments:

```
///<reference path="a.ts" />
```

For example, if you are running manually from the command line or using a tool that runs the command.